# How can I plot two surfaces that intersect each other

Tags: gnuplot

I've been trying to make 3d plots of surfaces from datasets using gnuplot. I have been partially successful using the following code:

```
set view 65,45
unset colorbox
set lmargin 14
set pm3d depthorder nohidden3d
set ylabel "angles [deg]"
set zlabel offset -2,0 "energy [eV]"
set palette defined (0 'blue', 1 "blue", 3 "blue", 4 'red')
splot "S1.dat" u 1:2:3:4 w pm3d  ti "S1", "T2.dat" u 1:2:3:4 w pm3d ti "T2"
```

which results in the following image:

[image1](http://s10.postimg.org/5gkzjjjh5/testimg.png)

The problem is, the border region (the "seam") between the two surfaces is not clearly visible because the tiles are colored with one color only. To make things clearer, here's what I obtain without pm3d (with or without hidden3d):

```
set terminal png size 800,800
set output "testimg2.png"
set view 65,45
unset colorbox
set lmargin 14
set isosamples 19,44
set hidden3d
set ylabel "angles [deg]"
set zlabel offset -2,0 "energy [eV]"
set palette defined (0 'blue', 1 "blue", 3 "blue", 4 'red')
#splot "S1.dat" u 1:2:3:4 w pm3d  ti "S1", "T2.dat" u 1:2:3:4 w pm3d ti "T2"
splot "S1.dat" u 1:2:3 w l lc rgb "blue"  ti "S1", "T2.dat" u 1:2:3 w l lc rgb "red" ti "T2"
unset hidden3d
set output "testimg3.png"
splot "S1.dat" u 1:2:3 w l lc rgb "blue"  ti "S1", "T2.dat" u 1:2:3 w l lc rgb "red" ti "T2"
```

[image 2 (hidden3d)](http://s8.postimg.org/halajqrmd/testimg2.png)

[image 3 (no hidden3d)](http://s24.postimg.org/53kws95j9/testimg3.png)

So essentially what I want is a picture like my second image, where you can clearly see the border between the surfaces, but with filled tiles.

The closest I've seen to this is fig 3 in the following page:

http://www.gnuplotting.org/klein-bottle/

where you can see where the bottle meets the handle.

Can anyone help? If this is not possible with gnuplot, can anyone suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

to plot 2 planes in 3d, enter functions for z, comma separated, e.g.

```
plane 1: 4x+2y+2z = 12
plane 2: -3x-2y+8z = 12
```

```
gnuplot> splot (-4*x-2*y+12)/2, (3*x+2*y+12)/8
```

[plot of 2 planes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9PO5.png)